# any linear non-constant polynomial in $F[x]$ is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field.

Use the formula $\deg(fg) = \deg (f) + \deg (g)$ to show that any linear
non-constant polynomial in $F[x]$ is irreducible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ is a linear polynomial, then $\text{deg }L = 1$.

If $L=fg$, then $\text{deg }L =\text{deg }f + \text{deg }g$, which is to say that $1 = \text{deg }f +\text{deg }g$, where $\text{deg }f, \text{deg }g \geq 0$.

Now, what are the possible combinations of $\text{deg }f$ and $\text{deg }g$?

Can you conclude, given that constants are polynomials of degree zero?

Comment: I don't understand the question and the answer. Consider =ℤ/ℤ and , where  is a prime number.

Comment: $Xp=0$, so it is not a linear non-constant polynomial.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you for pointing out the error, I was just coming to it. Indeed, $p=0$ in the ring $\mathbb Z \over p\mathbb Z$ so the polynomial $Xp$ equals $0$, which is not a linear non-constant polynomial.

Comment: Shame on me, @SarveshRavichandranIyer  I found it just moments ago, in the review queue (close) and I must really work on focusing on the date any post, first and foremost.  I spotted the date just before you commented. I reversed everything I did here.  Please accept my apology.